# Restucture XML Hierarchy with XSLT 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

In have an XML file with a structure of Transaction/isaPartners/Partner/Header/Item with multiple Partners under isaPartner.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Transactions>
    <isaPartners>
        <Partner partnerId="PartnerA">
            <Header currencyCode="USD" dateCreated="10/17/23" invoiceNumber="12345">
                <Item uom="EA" price="1.20" item="99987" />
            </Header>
        </Partner>
        <Partner partnerId="PartnerB">
            <Header currencyCode="USD" dateCreated="10/17/23" invoiceNumber="98765">
                <Item uom="EA" price="5.60" item="7765" />
            </Header>
        </Partner>
        <Partner partnerId="PartnerC" >
            <Header currencyCode="USD" dateCreated="10/17/23" invoiceNumber="45678">
                <Item uom="EA" price="6.50" item="1123" />
            </Header>
        </Partner>
    </isaPartners>
</Transactions>
```

I am trying to take all the Header/Item instances and put under one Partner/@partnerId that I can name whatever.

The output should be:
In this case I would take all the Header/Item under one Partner/@partnerID = PartnerD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Transactions>
    <isaPartners>
        <Partner partnerId="PartnerD">
            <Header currencyCode="USD" dateCreated="10/17/23" invoiceNumber="12345">
                <Item uom="EA" price="1.20" item="99987" />
            </Header>
            <Header currencyCode="USD" dateCreated="10/17/23" invoiceNumber="98765">
                <Item uom="EA" price="5.60" item="7765" />
            </Header>
            <Header currencyCode="USD" dateCreated="10/17/23" invoiceNumber="45678">
                <Item uom="EA" price="6.50" item="1123" />
            </Header>
        </Partner>
    </isaPartners>
</Transactions>
```

I'm not sure where to start so I don't have an example of what I tried.  I am familiar how to manipulate XML elements within a structure of an XML, but I'm lost on how to reorder the structure in this way.  Thanks in advance for any help!!

Answer (score 2):

This is a very basic task in xslt and will look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  
  <!-- Matches and copies all -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <!-- Matches and copies isaPartners and creates a new Partner and applies in that new Partner all Partner/Header -->
  <xsl:template match="isaPartners">
    <xsl:copy>
      <Partner partnerId="PartnerD">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Partner/Header"/>
      </Partner>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Siebe:  This worked great!  I'm surprised it was such a simple fix. I need to better understand how templates and elements are manipulated, especially with the copy tag.